# How do I get an event after the JTable GUI has been updated?

Tags: java, swing, events, jtable

I'm currently listening for the TabelModel's tableChanged() event however, this event fires before the JTable has actually updated/added the row to the GUI. I'm trying to re-adjust the table heights and need to know when the JTable has finished adding and displaying the row & it's contents.

Or is it possible to make the JTable set the row Height to the size of the component in each row? I tried to do so inside getCellRenderer but this just causes an endless loop of firing a tableChanged event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your code in the TableModelListener in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...). Thats adds the code to the end of the EDT so the table update should be completed when it executes.

Comment: This works however there is a noticeable delay between when the row get's added and the row gets resized. Is there a way to set the row height during the cell rendering process without having the JTable's setRowHeight(row, height) function trigger the tablechanged event?

Comment: There should be no delay (well milliseconds) when you do this. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. You should NOT be changing the the row height (or any table property) in the render. Presumabley you have a button like "Add Row" or something, so whenever the row is added the the table you should be adjusting the row height at that time. Then you can get rid of the TableModelListener.

Comment: Ahh you're correct my bad I had a Thread.sleep where I was trying something! Thank you so much!